# Responsive overlay div on custom Streetview map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, css-position, overlay, google-street-view

I am creating a custom indoor streetview of my university, so i have no LatLng values to add markers, is it possible to put an overlay on the map that will stay in one position on the image?

by this i mean if there is a div overlay ontop of a door, when moving the map the div overlay should move with the map and go off screen if necessary. 
(so basically a custom marker that does not need Latlng argument).

I've tried fiddling with the CSS position properties and have had no luck, is it possible to do?

Comment: It looks like you can't do that without lat/long. Overlays are tied to latitude/longitude coordinates, so they move when you drag or zoom the map.

Comment: you can do this simply using positioning. please provide basic code to work on

Comment: i have the first stage of the design on my site [link](http://www.cnolimit.co.uk/map), what i'm trying to do is put an overlay div over the reception area, but i what it to stay at the position, when moving the map like a marker. so u wont be able to see the div if you drag the map away from that area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css transitions here's my [Image overlay][1]

```
[1]: http://codepen.io/dfrierson2/pen/NPeOoJ

.gallery figure {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 315px;
        height: 268px;
        margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
        position: relative;
}
.gallery figcaption {
        position: absolute;
        width: 290px;
        height: 217px;
        bottom: 32px;
        left: 13px;
        right: 0px;
        top: 11px;
        opacity: 0;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;



}
.gallery figcaption:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity .3s ease-in;

}

<body>

<!--Image overlay starts here-->

        <div class="gallery">
      <h1>Image Overlay</h1>
            <figure>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/315x268"></a>
                <figcaption><img src="http://placehold.it/290x217"/></figcaption>
            </figure>



        </div>


</body>
```

Comment: this was not quite what i was looking, but nonetheless still helpful. i think i may need to use javascript to recalculate the position of the div when the map is dragged but i'm not sure how to do so.